# D AWS api authorization is not working

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, d

I'm trying to connect to AWS API in program written in D. I'm using the [vibe-aws module](https://github.com/yannick/vibe-aws/blob/master/source/vibe/aws/sigv4.d).

With small modification (removed `vibe.d` dependency, by copy paste missed 2 functions from it), all unit tests are passing. On top of it I wrote this program:

```
#!/usr/bin/rdmd -L-lcurl

import std.stdio;
import std.string;
import std.file;
import std.datetime;
import std.process;
import std.digest.sha;
import std.net.curl;
import std.uri;
import sigv4;


auto zone = "us-east-1";
auto service = "ec2";


void main()
{
    auto accKey = environment["AWS_ACCESS_KEY"];
    auto secKey = environment["AWS_SECRET_KEY"];

    auto currentClock = Clock.currTime(UTC());
    writeln(currentClock);
    auto currentDate = cast(Date)currentClock;
    auto curDateStr = currentDate.toISOString;

    writeln(curDateStr);

    auto currentTime = cast(TimeOfDay)currentClock;
    auto curTimeStr = currentTime.toISOString;

    writeln(curTimeStr);

    auto xamztime = curDateStr ~ "T" ~ curTimeStr ~ "Z";

    string[string] empty;

    SignableRequest r;
    r.dateString = curDateStr;
    r.timeStringUTC = curTimeStr;
    r.region = zone;
    r.service = service;
    r.canonicalRequest = CanonicalRequest(
                    "GET",
                    "/",
                    ["action" : "DescribeInstances", "version" : "2013-10-15"],
                    ["content-type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
                     "host" : service ~ ".amazonaws.com",
                     "x-amz-date" : xamztime],
                    cast(ubyte[])"");    




    writeln(signableString(r));

    auto qParm = canonicalQueryString(r.canonicalRequest.queryParameters);

    auto sigHead = canonicalHeaders(r.canonicalRequest.headers);

    auto sigStr = signableString(r);

    auto sigKey = signingKey(secKey, curDateStr, zone, service);

    auto signature = sign(sigKey, cast(ubyte[])sigStr).toHexString().toLower();

    writeln();  
    writeln(qParm);
    writeln();
    writeln(sigHead);
    writeln();
    writeln(sigStr);
    writeln();
    writeln(sigKey);
    writeln(signature);
    writeln();
    auto client = HTTP(service ~ ".amazonaws.com/?" ~ "Action=DescribeInstances&Version=2013-10-15");
    client.method = HTTP.Method.get;
    client.clearRequestHeaders;
    client.addRequestHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
    client.addRequestHeader("host", service ~ ".amazonaws.com");
    client.addRequestHeader("x-amz-date", xamztime);
    client.addRequestHeader("authorization", "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256" ~ " " ~ "Credential=" ~ accKey ~ "/" ~ xamztime ~ "/" ~ zone ~ "/" ~ service ~ "/" ~ "aws4_request" ~ ", " ~ "SignedHeaders=" ~ "content-type;host;x-amz-date" ~ ", " ~ "Signature=" ~ signature);
    auto content = client.perform();
    writeln(content);
}
```

Here is the output which I'm getting:

```
./header.d 
2015-Oct-11 16:54:01.208441Z
20151011
165401
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20151011T165401Z
20151011/us-east-1/ec2/aws4_request
f053e1901b164a712ed6c8384754673822d609da696b5d15799304835b3870ea

action=DescribeInstances&version=2013-10-15

content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
host:ec2.amazonaws.com
x-amz-date:20151011T165401Z


AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20151011T165401Z
20151011/us-east-1/ec2/aws4_request
f053e1901b164a712ed6c8384754673822d609da696b5d15799304835b3870ea

[116, 194, 23, 247, 184, 145, 90, 14, 192, 208, 97, 210, 77, 165, 201, 250, 6, 121, 49, 208, 142, 197, 33, 93, 204, 139, 11, 29, 227, 218, 107, 240]
57fdf77b44f2d14fa688b42bc88250a6ad2e6596964a6d40037333240ca15608

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response><Errors><Error><Code>AuthFailure</Code><Message>AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>2cf1443d-11b9-4a16-92e7-bf30c61e550b</RequestID></Response>0
```

Comment: You can test the results of your signing code with the examples provided in the Signature V4 test suite: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-test-suite.html

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but I have working S3 authorization in my unfinished library: https://github.com/sigod/s3-d/blob/master/source/s3/s3.d#L104

Comment: I used ready library for authorization process and i think it should work (all unit tests are passing). I find out that i did not use UTC  time but i changed it and still that same. What is strange when I'm putting data from unit test to my code it is generating other hashes. So problem is for 99% in my code but i cant find where.

Comment: I start to check everything from begging and i find out that unit test from sigv4 stops passing. Problem is with such function its generating wrong hash:

string hash(T)(T payload)
{
    auto hash = sha256Of(payload);
    return hash.toHexString().toLower();
}

string makeCRSigV4(CanonicalRequest r)
{
    auto cr =
        r.method.toUpper() ~ "\n" ~
        (r.uri.empty ? "/" : r.uri) ~ "\n" ~
        canonicalQueryString(r.queryParameters) ~ "\n" ~
        canonicalHeaders(r.headers) ~ "\n" ~
        signedHeaders(r.headers) ~ "\n" ~
        hash(r.payload);

    return hash(cr);
}

Comment: There's some problems with your code. First, why do you define the service as "ec2" but later on r.service as "iam"? Later down, your code uses the `service` variable, which will be ec2. So, have a look at that. Also, you're hardcoding the dates, which is absolutely not going to work when the AWS services validate your signature.
Also, the library you referred already has a SigV4 implementation. Why don't you just reuse it instead of creating your own? Here's what I'm talking about: https://github.com/yannick/vibe-aws/blob/master/source/vibe/aws/aws.d#L203

Comment: Sorry i paste my test version of code when i was checking signature values with unittests. Now i update it to proper one. I downloaded sigv4.d again and now all unittest are passing again but it still did not solve problem - im still getting auth failure.

Answer (score 0):

After long fight with previous code i try to rewrite "one-to-one" python example from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html (GET part) from begging to D with full success. Here is working code in clear D. Im using hmac function which is available from 2.069 of phobos). It is not too beautiful but im beginner, here it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/rdmd -L-lcurl

module sigawsv4;

import std.stdio, std.process;
import std.digest.sha, std.digest.hmac;
import std.string;
import std.conv;
import std.datetime;
import std.net.curl;

void main()
{
    auto accessKey = environment["AWS_ACCESS_KEY"];
    auto secretKey = environment["AWS_SECRET_KEY"];

    auto currentClock = Clock.currTime(UTC());

    auto currentDate = cast(Date)currentClock;
    auto curDateStr = currentDate.toISOString;

    auto currentTime = cast(TimeOfDay)currentClock;
    auto curTimeStr = currentTime.toISOString;

    auto xamztime = curDateStr ~ "T" ~ curTimeStr ~ "Z";


    string method = "GET";
    string service = "ec2";
    string host = "ec2.amazonaws.com";
    string region = "us-east-1";
    string endpoint = "https://ec2.amazonaws.com";
    string request_parameters = "Action=DescribeInstances&Version=2013-10-15";


    auto hmac_sha256(ubyte[] key, ubyte[] msg)
    {
        auto hmac = hmac!SHA256(key);
        hmac.put(msg);
        auto digest = hmac.finish;

        return digest;
    }

    alias sign = hmac_sha256;

    auto getSignatureKey(string key, string dateStamp, string regionName, string serviceName)
    {
        ubyte[] kString = cast(ubyte[])("AWS4" ~ key);
        auto kDate = sign(kString, cast(ubyte[])dateStamp);
        auto kRegion = sign(kDate, cast(ubyte[])regionName);
        auto kService = sign(kRegion,  cast(ubyte[])serviceName);
        auto kSigning = sign(kService, cast(ubyte[])"aws4_request");

        return kSigning;
    }


    string canonicalURI = "/";
    string canonicalQueryString = request_parameters;
    string canonicalHeadersString =  "host:" ~ host ~ "\n" ~ "x-amz-date:" ~ xamztime ~ "\n";
    string signedHeaders = "host;x-amz-date";
    string payloadHash = sha256Of("").toHexString.toLower;
    string canonicalRequest = method ~ "\n" ~ canonicalURI ~ "\n" ~ canonicalQueryString ~ "\n" ~ canonicalHeadersString ~ "\n" ~ signedHeaders ~ "\n" ~ payloadHash;


    string algorithm = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256";
    string credentialScope = curDateStr ~ "/" ~ region ~ "/" ~ service ~ "/" ~ "aws4_request";
    string stringToSign = algorithm ~ "\n" ~ xamztime ~ "\n" ~ credentialScope ~ "\n" ~ sha256Of(canonicalRequest).toHexString.toLower;

    auto signingKey = getSignatureKey(secretKey, curDateStr, region, service);

    string signature = hmac_sha256(signingKey, cast(ubyte[])stringToSign).toHexString.toLower;

    string authorizationHeader = algorithm ~ " " ~ "Credential=" ~ accessKey ~ "/" ~ credentialScope ~ ", " ~ "SignedHeaders=" ~ signedHeaders ~ ", " ~ "Signature=" ~ signature;

    auto client = HTTP(endpoint ~ "?" ~ canonicalQueryString);
    client.method = HTTP.Method.get;
    client.addRequestHeader("x-amz-date", xamztime);
    client.addRequestHeader("Authorization", authorizationHeader);
    auto content = client.perform();

    writeln(content);
}
```